# Php search function displaying null

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

Hi guys so i am just using learning php for the first time and building my own site etc to try it out. I have a database of recipes. For each recipe it has a list of ingredients. Each recipe will have different amounts. So one will have 5, the other can have 3 etc. The problem with my code is. If someone searches for a recipe and they find it, it will return the ingredients but sometimes if it has more than the divs i put there it will give some null values back. Also i understand about the sql injections etc and the bad practice but i am just playing about with it first. I want to get it to work and then fix that part later :)

PHP:

```
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading"><b>' . htmlentities($rN, ENT_QUOTES) . '</b></div>
                                </a>

    }

?>
```

Now i am pretty sure in my white loop i am suppose to do an if statement after the div tags and say if the value == null then dont display but i have tried and nothing has worked so any help on this matter would be great

Thanks

Comment: It all works fine, its just the extra divs i put in the while loop , as some recipes have more than 3 ingredients

Comment: @fusion3k so the search function works all fine, its just as i said, some recipes have more than 3 ing it will display a null on the 4th and 5th item

Comment: So i just need an if statment around the 4th and 5th div to check if its null and not to post it

Comment: Yes. See my answer for general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML for ingredients seems be repeating, so you can resolve the empty `<div>` issue and short your code using a `for` loop and a `if` condition:

```
$output .= '<div class="panel panel-default">
            (...)
            <h3 class="media-heading">INGREDIENTS:</h3>';

for( $i=1; $i < 7; $i++ )
{
    if( ${"rI$i"} )
    {
        $output .= '<div class="food-graph">
            <span class="food-graph-title">' . htmlentities(${"rI$i"}, ENT_QUOTES) . '</span>
        </div>';
    }
}

$output .= ' (...) ';
```

Comment: Sorry does this go instead of whiile loop?>

Comment: If possible i know its hassle but can u just copy and paste the whole code and were this is suppose to go, as i am struggling to get it to work

Comment: Ah this is brilliant , thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 1):

If encountering null values is a problem, this will only print out the ingredients that your row contains.

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $rN = $row['recipeName'];
        $i=1;
        $recipes = '';
        if (isset($row['recipe_ing'.$i]) {
            while(isset($row['recipe_ing'.$i]) {
                $value =  htmlentities($row['recipe_ing'.$i], ENT_QUOTES);
                $recipes .= <<< EOT
<div class="food-graph">
    <span class="food-graph-title">$value</span>
</div>                
EOT;
                $i++;
            }

            $output .= <<< EOT
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><b>' . htmlentities($rN, ENT_QUOTES) . '</b></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="pull-left col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-thumbnail img-responsive" src="Image/green.jpg">
                </a>
                <a class="btn btn-success btn-block btnrec" href="#">View Recipe</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h3 class="media-heading">INGREDIENTS:</h3>
$recipes
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">Rating</div>
</div>
EOT;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** Also, i'm using Heredocs to set the strings. the lines with **EOT;** must have no whitespace or code in front of it. it must be at the start of the line. also no code may be on the same line behind it. Else, your documents will become a huge string.

Comment: while(isset($row['recipe_ing'.$i]) {

Comment: forgot a parenthesis on the while. try again

Comment: Wil try now  and see

Comment: shows all the ing fine, but still shows 0 for the ones below

Comment: I'm confused, ingredients show fine, got that. what still shows 0?

Comment: So for example it will show the 3 ing for 1 recipe but the etcs will still be there as 0

Comment: Ah I see, let me add a case for you

Comment: I've added an if statement that will ensure it will try and add ingredients if atleast 1 ingredient is set.